# JavaFX - How to use ImageView methods on Object type?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to create an EventHandler for the mouse dragged event. I'll use this same handler to do the same thing with several ImageViews. Now this is what I did.

```
static EventHandler<MouseEvent> dragHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            e.getSource().toFront();
            e.getSource().setTranslateX(e.getSceneX() );
            e.getSource().setTranslateY(e.getSceneY() );

        }

        };
```

But apparently I can't use toFront or setTranslate methods or anything that I used for ImageViews because e.getSource returns an Object and these are ImageView methods that are not available to Object type. And apparently I can't simply cast that into an ImageView either by doing

```
   (ImageView)( e.getSource() ).toFront();
```

I could simply use inner classes and lambda expressions but I thought there must be a more efficient way than just copy pasting the same lines like 15 times for each ImageView. So please enlighten me if there is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting would work, but the precedence of casting is below that of dereferencing (`.`), so your code example tries to downcast the result of `(e.getSource()).toFront()`, which doesn't work (as that has no type, since `toFront()` is `void`).

So

```
((ImageView) e.getSource() ).toFront();
```

would work.

However, it's usually better to register a different handler for each image view. There's no need to repeat code: just use any standard programming technique to avoid doing so. E.g. you can write a method:

```
private void registerEventHandler(ImageView imageView) {
    imageView.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
        imageView.toFront();
        imageView.setTranslateX(e.getSceneX() );
        imageView.setTranslateY(e.getSceneY() );
    });

    // register other event handlers, as needed.
}
```

and then call the method for each image view (in a loop, if you have them in some suitable data structure).

Alternatively, you could create a method that creates the image views and registers any necessary handlers.

As well as being arguably cleaner code, these techniques also avoid the downcast, which in general is a good thing.

Comment: That downcasting does work. I was misplacing my parantheses. I couldn't think of simply writing a method for that either. Probably because I'm too lost in trying my first thought which is downcasting. Thank you for both of these answers.